# D3 js coding special symbols usage in TreeDiagram size change with .size() attribute data related

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Totally new (never coded anything), but slowly evolving enthusiast of D3 js. I'd like to show some financial data in a new manner at my workplace, which I consider cool and interesting.

By means of different techniques ( reading, learning, finally putting different pieces of code together of those who can code well) I achieved pretty good results and to my surprise it worked, namely Treediagram with children nodes.

1. There is one thing I can not get done, I want to change the size of special symbols (bigger numbers -> bigger symbol) by relating them to data by means of scale to make them visible & scalable.
2. Below what I tried to do:

-- fragment of data

```
data =  [{"name":"AA ","parent":"null","actual":391,"plan":349,"year":349,"children": [
```

{"name":"AB ","parent":"AA","actual":11346,"plan":14429,"year":14429,},
{"name":"AC ","parent":"AA","actual":559,"plan":558,"year":558,},]}]

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d[2]; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[2]; })])
.range([100, 200]);

... some code ....

nodeEnter.append("path")
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("fill", function(d) {        
    var a = d.actual ;
    var y = d.year;
    if ( a/y > 1 && a/y <= 1.2 ) { return "rgb(255,192,203)";}
        else if (a/y > 1.2) { return "rgb(255,0,0)";}   
        else if (a/y > 0 && a/y <= 0.8) { return "rgb(34,139,34)";}
        else if (a/y > 0.8 && a/y < 1) { return "rgb(152,251,152)";}
        else { return "rgb(255,255,0)";}
        }   
     )
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
    .size(xScale(d[2])) 
    .type(function(d) { if
        (d.actual - d.year> 0) { return "triangle-down"; } else if
        (d.actual - d.year < 0) { return "triangle-up";} else
        { return "square";}
    })
);
```

2. With just .size(200) all work well with .size(xScale(d[2]), no way. I know that despite reading a lot of articles and tutorials (never encountered a solution) I know nothing, so You are my last resort. I need just a little hint where to look for solution.

Thank You for your time & help
Zbyszek (PL)

Comment: what is d[2]? from your data d is not an array

Comment: Thanks, it was supposed to be json structure and it works like one and I try to refer to the second element of it and obviously I can't which I now understand. But how to refer to that nested array ?

Comment: d.children[0] for example is the object with name "AB"

Comment: :-) Thanks a lot, step by step I learn more and more, by the way, You could explain the very question nurturing me and related to the topic above : is it possible to change .size of the SYMBOL NODE (for instance triangle) using SCALE method and relate the input data to output range. As a matter of fact this is the question I try to ask :-) ..thanks for help and so far suport Zbyszek

Comment: :-) I add some example to the above said to be more explicit .. Data = [1,3,[1,3,5], 5,8] my range namely the size of the tirangle is limited to [200,300] i would like to relate data to range which is the presentation of the triangle size. I stopped at this point. So far i use if statement to choose the size of the triangle but fantasize to automate it, maybe my efforts are pointless ?